# In tinymce,if selector:'textarea'..And inside textarea present in body ,row col not applied

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

```js
 tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste imagetools","autosave"],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        
       

});
```

```html
<textarea>
  
<!--    start your work from here-->
   <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        hi
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        hi
       </div>
    
    </div>
<!--        end your work-->
</textarea>
```

Result shows both col in new line..Now,How can I use my code in simple bootstrap.Or what will be the bootstrap plugin .

Answer (score 1):

To use bootstrap css in TinyMCE editor you need to specify your css in `init` function as following

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  content_css : 'bootstrap.css'
});
```